# imageView in TableView from json array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, tableview

I'm working in a simple IOS app with objective-c, and i want to load an image to the table cell. 
I have a litle web service that give me a json data like this:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Papas","description":"Papas chilotas negras","images":
[{"url":"/uploads/product/images/1/8282486574_382f59c31e_o.jpg",  
"thumb":"url":"/uploads/product/images/1/
thumb_8282486574_382f59c31e_o.jpg"},
"catalog":"url":"/uploads/product/images/1/
catalog_8282486574_382f59c31e_o.jpg"},
"big":"url":"/uploads/product/images/1/
big_8282486574_382f59c31e_o.jpg"}}],
"price":1200,"stand_id":3,"created_at":"2017-10-
24T04:01:09.000Z","updated_at":"2017-10-24T04:01:09.000Z"}]
```

I had set up the name and description like this [tableCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkiaH.png)

The problem is how do i access the path to the thumb version of the image to show it in the table cell.

this is the code i have to populate the table

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text=[dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"description"];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is this a valid JSON?

Comment: URL is invalid -> `"thumb" : "url" : " /uploads/product/... /_o.jpg"` <- never seen this type of json. So iam closing this post as a uncleared question.

Comment: the json data came from this url http://18.221.78.126/ecoferia/api/products it came from a rails app with mysql db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON in [this](http://18.221.78.126/ecoferia/api/products) link and the JSON you provided in you question is different.

According to the JSON in link, this is how you can parse it :

```
[[[[dictionary objectForKey:@"images"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"thumb"] valueForKey:@"url"];
```

Comment: @AndresAldana Great. Please accept and upvote the answer then.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON data that you gave is wrong. The right type is

```
("thumb" : "/uploads/product/images/1/thumb_8282486574_382f59c31e_o.jpg" ),
```

no "url".

So, you can get thumb images dictinary:

```
NSArray * arr = dictionary[@"images"];
```

such as

```
[arr[0] objectForKey:@"thumb"];
```